# Random error on dataTaskWithRequest completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, passbook, passkit

I'm working on a passbook capable swift application and i'm in front of a strange problem.
Randomly, the passbook i download from my server is corrupted (the same downloaded can be good or corrupted).

Here is the code :

```
func openPass(pass: PKPass)
{
    let passname = "Benight Ticket"
    var passcontroller = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: pass)
    passcontroller.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(passcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func getTicketPassbook()
{
    let TicketID: String = "2gBOZqWwNj"
    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://exemple.com/index.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString: String = "ObjectId=" + TicketID + "&authKey=\"exemple\""
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        println("response = \(response)")
        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            if (statusCode == 200)
            {
            println("Success: \(statusCode)")
            var pkfile : NSData = NSData(data: data)
                var pass: PKPass = PKPass(data: pkfile, error: nil)
                self.openPass(pass)
            }
            // This is your file-variable:
            // data
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            println("Faulure: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    })
    task.resume()
 }
```

The error is the following : 2015-08-22 16:18:28.328 Application[10302:1018965] BOM could not extract archive: Couldn't read PKZip signature

And other times it works.... It's really at random times that it works or fail...

EDIT : Sometis i've also the following error : 2015-08-23 01:19:19.483 Benight[3467:994898] Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.apple.demo/8j23fm3. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Have you ruled out if the error is with your web server?

Comment: Yes, if error on server it get an error 500

Comment: Issue appears to be with your server and the quality/integrity of the .pkpass bundles you are downloading.  The specific error you quote relates to a signing.  Ensure your server is including the WWDR certificate and that the signature contains a timestamp.

Comment: Yes, On the server side i've also a webpage that perm it to download it directly and it's works 100% time

Comment: you can download a sample of my passbook on https://tickets.benight.cc/ it's use exactly the same code to generate it than the server of my app except it's blocked on one value